# Hibernate QueryException

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

Hello I am trying to reference in a Criteria a property of a composite key which is defined as and @Embeddable on an Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B_J_P")
public class BJP implements java.io.Serializable {

private BJPId id;
private BJI bJI;

public BJP() {
}

public BJP(BJPId id, BJI bJI) {
this.id = id;
this.bJI = bJI;
}

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides( {
    @AttributeOverride(name = "jIId", column = @Column(name = "J_I_ID", nullable = false)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "kN", column = @Column(name = "K_N", nullable = false, length = 100)),

public BJPId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "J_I_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public BJI getBJI() {
    return this.bJI;
}
}
```

I need to reach the kName from the following:

```
@Embeddable
public class BJPId implements java.io.Serializable {


private long jIId;
private String kName;

public BJPId() {
}

public BJPId(long jIId, String kN) {
    this.jIId = jIId;
    this.kN = kN;
}

@Column(name = "J_I_ID", nullable = false)
public long getJIId() {
    return this.jIId;
}

@Column(name = "K_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getKName() {
    return this.kName;
}
}
```

But when I am trying to reach it from the base class where BJP is a property with the following Criteria

```
DetachedCriteria timestampFilter = DetachedCriteria.forClass(BJP.class)
            .createAlias("id","alias")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("alias.kName","DataSetName"))
            .setProjection(Projections.property("kName"));
```

I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: id
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPathInfo
```

How should I formulate the criteria query in order to reach the kName property to apply filtering based on it in a dynamic sql context ?

If I have not provided enough relevant information, please ask what have I forgotten to provide full context.

EDIT: Upon Genzetto advice I have managed to reach the elements(at least it is not giving errors now) but returns no results once I do this:

```
DetachedCriteria timestampFilter = DetachedCriteria.forClass(BJP.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id.kName","DataSetName"))
            .setProjection(Projections.property("id.kName"));
Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria query = currentSession.createCriteria(BJI.class)
            .add(Subqueries.propertyEq("bJP",timestampFilter))
```

as upon looking at the SQL it is of the format

```
... where this_.J_INST_ID = (select this_.K_NAME as y0_ from .B_J_P this_ where this_.K_NAME=?)
```

it is trying to add the subquery to the ID of the root object although I want it part of bJP. How can I add it to proper location ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an alias to do this. You can access directly to the composite key attributes:

```
DetachedCriteria timestampFilter = DetachedCriteria.forClass(BJP.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id.kName","DataSetName"))
            .setProjection(Projections.property("id.kName"));
```

Comment: Thank you! Your comment helped, unfortunately run into an issue further down, do you know solution to my current issue by any chance please?

Comment: What issue did you get?

Comment: Do you have a bjP field inside your BJI class? Could you post your BJI class code?